# how to post with the following method Here

Tags: ios, url, post, swift3

I want to post pictures With swift 3.0 - I saw this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krZzC6abaoE

But this is for Swift 2.0

here is my codes that doesn't work because of the Line

```
let uploadScriptUrl = URL(String : "http://www.swiftdeveloperblog.com/http-post-example-script/")
```

and I can't Run the app

```
  func uploadFiles() {

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(customKindImage.image!, 1)

    if (imageData == nil ) {

        print("There is Not Any Images to upload!")



        let uploadScriptUrl = URL(String : "http://www.swiftdeveloperblog.com/http-post-example-script/")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: uploadScriptUrl!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("Keep-Alive" , forHTTPHeaderField : "Connection")


        var configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        var session = URLSession(configuration : configuration , delegate : self as? URLSessionDelegate , delegateQueue : OperationQueue.main)

        var task = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request , fromData : imageData)

        task.resume()

    }


}
```

I have This Method In ViewDidLoad For Image And That Image Will Be Upload

```
        if customKind.text == "خدمات تایپ" {

            customKindImage.image = UIImage(named:"Key.png")


        } else if customKind.text == "دیگر خدمات" {

            customKindImage.image = UIImage(named: "doc.png")

        } else if customKind.text == "خدمات ترجمه"  {

            customKindImage.image = UIImage(named:"Translate.png")

        }
```

Comment: It Shows But As You know in the method for Update I will Receive Error ? How can I solve this problem? please help me

Comment: If you are having image in imageView then try to debug the upload method by putting break point and check once on which line it is crashing

Comment: Thanks I will Try To Do that

Comment: So I will Ask My question In another question In this Site :
That Will be how to sent an array of pictures with this code

Comment: Yes go for it mate :)

Comment: So Here Is My next Question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952631/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-pictures-which-following-method-here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952631/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-pictures-which-following-method-here
please help me to find the answer

Comment: thanks for your guides Here - Ok I will wait hope to get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is it is `init(string:)` not the `init(String:)`, here `s` is small also from swift 3 URLRequest's method's property is named as `httpMethod` not the `HTTPMethod`.

Now with Swift 3 use mutable object of [`URLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/URLResponse) instead of `NSMutableURLRequest` also instead of delegate use completion block with [`uploadTask(with:from:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1411518-uploadtask).

```
func uploadFiles() {

    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(customKindImage.image!, 1) {            
        print("There is Not Any Images to upload!")

        let uploadScriptUrl = URL(string : "http://www.swiftdeveloperblog.com/http-post-example-script/")
        var request = URLRequest(url: uploadScriptUrl!)            
        request.httpMethod = "POST"            
        request.setValue("Keep-Alive" , forHTTPHeaderField : "Connection")

        let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: imageData, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                return
            }
            //access data here
        })            
        task.resume()
    }       
}
```

Comment: I Receive This Error When Use this code 
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-05-13 14:55:44.870939+0430

Comment: I have an Image view that will take one of the apps Images

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi On which line it is crashing first tell that

Comment: I Think in this line         if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(customKindImage.image!, 1) {

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi That means your imageView customKindImage doesn't having any image you need to set image that you want to upload

Comment: Wait I will Update The question Codes