# How Can I post An Array of Pictures With Following Method Here

Tags: ios, arrays, url, post, swift3

I am Using Swift 3 and want to post an Array of pictures with this method - please help how can I do that

```
if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(customKindImage.image! , 1) {
  print("There is Not Any Images to upload!")

  let uploadScriptUrl = URL(string : "http://www.swiftdeveloperblog.com/http-post-example-script/")
  var request = URLRequest(url: uploadScriptUrl!)
  request.httpMethod = "POST"
  request.setValue("Keep-Alive" , forHTTPHeaderField : "Connection")

  let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: imageData, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
      guard let _ = data, error == nil else {
          print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
          return
      }
      //access data here
  })            
  task.resume()
}
```

and here is my Array

```
var photoes : [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "1.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "2.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "3.jpg")!]
```

Comment: u have a `String` array, not a `UIImage` array. your code will never get past at the first `if` statement.

Comment: I Edited the question with right Image Array